# Search string letters with array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach

I got this little puzzle today to resolve:

```
var str = "hzuelgdlbo";
var arr = [0, 3, 4, 7, 9];
console.log(res); => "hello"
```

I solved it with a simple **forEach** and I'm now asking me if there is a easier solution (custom sorts) for this.

```
forEach:
idz.forEach(function(idx){    
    var res = [];
    res.push(str[idx]);   
    console.log(res.join(''));
});
```

One solution would be maybe looping over the array and doing a substr on the string.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
[0, 3, 4, 7, 9].reduce(function(p, c) { return p + "hzuelgdlbo"[c] }, '')
```

or something similar using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
[0, 3, 4, 7, 9].map(function(i) { return "hzuelgdlbo"[i] }).join('');
```

---

You can wrap both in a console.log / alert to output the value.

Answer (score 1):

This solution creates and array of letter, and transform them to a string only at the end. It can also return the result without using an external variable:

```
arr.reduce(function (word, letterIndex) {
    word.push(str[letterIndex]);
    return word;
}, []).join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `filter` the elements from the string (that you first convert into an array):

```
var str = "hzuelgdlbo".split('').filter(function(el, i, a) {
    if (arr.indexOf(i) > -1) return el;
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

using map http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/zx1w9hdw/:

```
var str     = "hzuelgdlbo";
var numbers = [0, 3, 4, 7, 9];

mapp = function(_array,_str){
    return (_array.map(function(n){ return _str[n]; })).join('');
};

console.log(mapp(numbers,str));
```